# HttpHeaders de Angular no envia ninguna cabeceras

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jwt, spring-security, cors

Tengo un problema como el modulo de HttpHeaders en angular 7, que me esta fallando al hacer una peticion a una api en spring con jwt. tengo los origenes {http://::4200(cliente), http://::8080(serve api)}.

He probado con nodejs y el módulo de `request`, con postman, con **jquery** y con todos estos me funciona, menos con angular y su módulo de **httpClient**, **httpHeader**.

Lo que asumo es que no me esta enviando las cabeceras '`Autorization`', puesto que al buscarla con el objeto `HttpServletRequest` el resultado es '`null`'.

*en mi cliente he configurado los `headers` asi:*

```
  httpOptions = {
       headers: new HttpHeaders({
         'authorization' : 'Bearer <token>',
         'content-type': 'application/json',
         'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : "*"
       })
  };
```

*en mi server*

```
   @RestController
   @RequestMapping("/author")
   @CrossOrigin(
    origins = "*",
    allowedHeaders = {"Content-Type", "Authorization", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"}
    )
  public class AuthorsController { ... }


   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
   public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
         protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
               .csrf().disable()
               .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/authenticate").permitAll()
               .anyRequest().authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
               .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
               .and()
               .sessionManagement()
               .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);
               http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, 
               UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Ya he probado de todo y nada. No muestro el filtro puesto que como comente anteriormente ni siquiera puedo obtener el header '`authorization`' asi que el filtro ni siquiera para de ahi, ya que el resultado al no existir ese `header` es `null`.

Answer (score 0):

intenta con

```
  httpOptions = {
   headers: new HttpHeaders({
     'Authorization' : 'Bearer <token>',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : "*"
   })
```

};

y cuéntame como te va ya que e leido que en PHP en algunas versiones las cabeceras son Case Sensitive.

Comment: Gracias Manuel. Ya he hecho esa configuracion. De hecho me he leido Cors in Action y Cors Essential para ver si era error de configuracion y tengo bien en ambos origenes. He configurado un proxy, un interceptor en el cliente y nada. Ni siquiera llegan a mi backen porque al filtrar esos headers el resultado es null.  :/

Comment: Ya lo he resuelto, el problema estaba en que ignoraba que normalmente spring security agregaba unos headers por defecto, y solo basto con resetearlas con una simple configuracion de CORS con los respose headers deseados y solicitar ese bean en el filtro y voila! Problema resuelto!

Gracias!